# JSX element type 'ReactNotifications' does not have any construct or call signatures.ts(2604)

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am running react with typescript. I have following code:

```
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import initStore from './store'
import TestApp from './TestApp'
import ReactNotifications from 'react-notifications-component'


const store = initStore()

function App() {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <ReactNotifications />
      <TestApp />
    </Provider>
  );
}

export default App
```

According to the documentation on the `react-notifictaion-component` this should work, but I am getting error message with the `RactNotifications` component highlighted:

```
JSX element type 'ReactNotifications' does not have any construct or call signatures.ts(2604)
```

I have also installed `@types/react-notifications-component` thinking that it might solve problem. Am I overlooking something? Thanks for your time helping out.

Answer (score 0):

Yes I was overlooking the fact that to call the ReactNotifications as of version 3 I have to use `import { ReactNotifications } from 'react-notifications-component'`